# cheapest OpenCV board

Tags: motherboard

I'm working on a small project that require computer vision boards. As many as possible.
Wifi ability is not necessary, I can get ESP8266-01s with a dollar.

OpenMV is too expensive and not easy to deploy.
Rasp Zero W is OK, but my board stopped functioning three day after I bought it.
I'm now using Nanopi Duo2, have issues installing miniconda, but it is the best choice I know.

I tried ESP32-CAM a year ago, but it seems impossible to use python on it.